# Dell Wireless Keyboard and Mouse - Intermittent Freezing

Tags: keyboard, mouse, dell, 18.10

**Issue**

Wireless mouse and keyboard, works for a little bit, then starts freezing intermittently, to the point of becoming unusable. It works without a problem in OSX. Tried putting new batteries on both, but still no use. Searched a lot to find a solution, but nothing works.

**System Information**

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- Dell Km117 Wireless Keyboard Mouse
- Ubuntu 18.10
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz × 8
- Graphics: Intel® Haswell Mobile
- GNOME: 3.30.1

**Diagnostic Information**

**1. dmesg**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg
...
[   78.041877] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   78.198002] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04ca, idProduct=009b, bcdDevice= 3.25
[   78.198005] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   78.198007] usb 1-1: Product: Wireless Device
[   78.198009] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Lite-On Technology Corp.
[   78.202106] input: Lite-On Technology Corp. Wireless Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:04CA:009B.0009/input/input21
[   78.262023] hid-generic 0003:04CA:009B.0009: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Lite-On Technology Corp. Wireless Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[   78.265480] input: Lite-On Technology Corp. Wireless Device Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:04CA:009B.000A/input/input22
[   78.265583] input: Lite-On Technology Corp. Wireless Device Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:04CA:009B.000A/input/input23
[   78.321810] input: Lite-On Technology Corp. Wireless Device System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:04CA:009B.000A/input/input24
[   78.321952] hid-generic 0003:04CA:009B.000A: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Lite-On Technology Corp. Wireless Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
```

**2. lspci**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Crystal Well DRAM Controller (rev 08)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Crystal Well PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 08)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Crystal Well PCI Express x8 Controller (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Crystal Well Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 08)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Crystal Well HD Audio Controller (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 SATA controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a801 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC (rev 01)
04:00.0 Multimedia controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
06:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
06:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
06:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
06:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
07:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 NHI [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
```

**2. lsusb**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8406 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:ab26 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8290 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:0274 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04ca:009b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Similar issue here with a generic wireless keyboard+mouse. No matter how full the batteries are, the issue occurs many times a day.